# adding data to a stack implemented using 2 structs in C: moving pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, stack

I'm struggling to move the pointer from 1 element of a stack to the next. I have completed the implementation. The last element of the stack is given but otherwise nothing I try seems to work. The compiler gives the error `next undeclared (first use of this function)` on the line `pNewNode->next=next`

Relevant code is below:

```
void push( TopStack *ts, int val)
{
    if(ts->num==0)
    {
        Stack *pNewNode;
        pNewNode=(Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
        pNewNode->val=val;
        pNewNode->next=NULL;
        ts->top=pNewNode;
    }
    else if(ts->num!=0)
    {
        Stack *pNewNode;
        pNewNode=(Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
        pNewNode->val=val;
        pNewNode->next=next;
        ts->top=pNewNode;
    }
}
```

The structs are defined here:

```
typedef struct stack_elem
{
    int val;
    struct stack_elem *next;
} Stack;

//struct that contains the pointer to the top of the stack

typedef struct
{
    int num; //num of elements in stack
    Stack *top;; //top of stack
} TopStack;
```

I also have the relevant prototypes for the functions below, as the structs are in a header file. For ease of reading I have only included what I think is the relevant code but I can provide more if needed.

Comment: `pNewNode->next=next;` `next` isn't defined.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does it compile and do nothing or there are compilation errors?

Comment: When you want to add the new node on ***top*** of the stack, where should the new nodes `next` pointer be pointing?

Comment: I get it: `pNewNode->next=ts->next;` Voting to close.

Comment: surely next is the pointer to the next element of the stack? I know I have made a syntax error, but I cant figure out what to use in its place; everything I try returns the same error

Comment: The pointer `pNewNode` will become the new top node. The next node after should be the old top node. At that point, when you assign to `pNewNode->next`, what is the "old" top node?

Comment: pNewNode->next=ts->next; nearly works, but the structure TopStack does not include the member next. do you mean     pNewNode->next=ts->top; ?

Comment: Some Programmer Dude, the old top node should be "pushed" down, and have the node that is placed on top of it be linked to it. the node containing the NULL pointer should not link anywhere, as it is the last node of the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please modify your code in else part pNewNode->next=ts->top;

```
void push( TopStack *ts, int val)
{
    if(ts->num==0)
    {
       Stack *pNewNode;
       pNewNode=(Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
       pNewNode->val=val;
       pNewNode->next=NULL;
       ts->top=pNewNode;
   }
   else if(ts->num!=0)
   {
       Stack *pNewNode;
       pNewNode=(Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
       pNewNode->val=val;
       pNewNode->next=ts->top;
       ts->top=pNewNode;
   }
}
```